# How to make Visual C++ build register the dlls with browser?

Tags: visual-c++

I'm using Visual C++ 6.0 Enterprise Edition.
In one visual c++ project when I build, it says 
Linking...
Performing registration
Creating browse info file...

I don't know what project settings make this happen, I want the same to happen in another visual c++ project. Please reply, before I shoot myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project Properties, C/C++, Browse Information: Set "Enable Browse Information" and specify a "Browse File"

Comment: In Project "Settings", under C/C++ tab, I only see a check box "Generate browser info". Checking this box does not cause the registration to happen. I dont find the "Enable Browse Information" input.

Comment: Then you're not using the same VS version I do, edit your question to include VS version